# Variable's don't show up after applying a function that should create a variable

Tags: r, function, parameters

I have this code below, but it doesn't produce what I expect.

I would expect that when I run this code, I would create two new variables in the environment tab: x_num and x_vector. And x_vector would be a vector of 2000 values that go from 0.01 to 20.0, but this does not show up.

How can this be?

```
x_num <- 2000
x_step <- 0.01
INFSMALL <- 1e-4
B <- 20

CreateLocation <- function() 
{
  seq(x_num)*x_step
}

Initialization <- function()
{
  x_num    <- as.integer((B+INFSMALL)/x_step)
  x_vector <- CreateLocation()
}
Initialization()
```

Comment: Use `<<-` instead of `<-`

Comment: In which part? the parameters, functions or inside the initialization function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`?"<<-"` gives *The operators ‘<<-’ and ‘->>’ are normally only used in functions, and cause a search to be made through parent environments for an existing definition of the variable being assigned.  If such a variable is found (and its binding is not locked) then its value is redefined, otherwise assignment takes place in the global environment.*

```
Initialization <- function()
{
  x_num    <<- as.integer((B+INFSMALL)/x_step)
  x_vector <<- CreateLocation()
}
Initialization()
str(x_vector)
# num [1:2000] 0.01 0.02 0.03 0.04 0.05 0.06 0.07 0.08 0.09 0.1 ...
```

Comment: So just for me to understand properly. Which one is correct:
1. I should use <<- for every assignment happening in a function or 2 I should use <<- every time I assign a function to a variable inside a function.

Comment: For assignment which you want to happen in a parent environment and if they are not found there than in the global environment.

Comment: @VictorNielsen - When you create a variable inside a function, it is usually only accessible within the environment outside that function. Use `<<-` if you want to create a variable inside a function and have it become part of the parent environment (usable outside the function) .

Answer (score 1):

It is discouraged to write to global environment from within the function, you should just `return` the values that you need from the function. If there are multiple values that you need return a list.

```
Initialization <- function()
{
  x_num    <- as.integer((B+INFSMALL)/x_step)
  x_vector <- CreateLocation()
  list(x_num = x_num, x_vector = x_vector)
}

result <- Initialization()
```

`result` has list of length 2 and you can access individual items using `result$x_num` and `result$x_vector`. If it is absolutely necessary to have them as separate variables `x_num` and `x_vector` you can use `list2env`.

```
list2env(result, .GlobalEnv)
```